# Designing classes around a StAX parsing

Tags: java, xml, design-patterns

This is a design question rather than a Java-specific question, but I'm designing it for Java.

I've been writing some XML pull parsing classes to handle a custom XML response and as I design them, I can't help but think whether there's something better. Maybe someone even has a design pattern for it.

So, here's what my XML may look like:

```
<ResponseRoot>
  <Header>
    <RequestId />
    <OtherHeaderMetaData />
  </Header>
  <Body>
    ...
    <!-- Lots of other elements and nested elements -->
    ...
  </Body>
</ResponseRoot>
```

So depending on the `RequestId` (a key of sorts), the `Body` element is different. Given that this is pull parsing, I'd have a large switch statement and lots of if-else-if blocks.

Would it be more efficient for one class with lots of static methods to handle the whole XML stream, or would it make for a better design to have one class responsible for each `RequestId`?

I was thinking of mapping `RequestId` to a class name, and then when I hit `Body`, I use a factory to retrieve the appropriate subparser. Inside that factory, I could even use a mapping of `Class` instances and use reflection to instantiate the appropriate parser (since not all parsers are needed all the time). Or... use reflection to grab the appropriate static parsing *method* instead, so I don't need to instantiate parsers that are really just 1-use classes...

Yea, I'm thinking too deeply, but since this is just a personal project, I just got curious about how people design parsing classes around a StAX parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So depending on the RequestId (a key of sorts), the Body element is different.

Can you redesign the XML so that a valid body elemt does not depend on the request-ID, but is determined entirely by the surrounding response element? Then document validity (conformance to the DTD) would correspond to message response validity.

Instead of using a `switch` statement, consider using the [state design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern). That is, implement your document handler as a finite state machine.

Answer (score 2):

I'd definitely go for a separate processor class per request type. Your factory approach sounds good, but don't bother with the reflection stuff, just create those processor objects instead of using reflection, thirty-something bytes of heap space are a very reasonable price for easily readable code.

One thing that is important though with StAX that in the documentation of every processing method you should describe what state that method is expecting the input to be in (e.g.: before or after having processed the opening `<body>` tag) and where does it leave the input after processing. You can save yourself hours of frustrating debugging this way.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting the responsibility of parsing each custom XML object on the StAX parser, why not have the StAX parser create an intermediate representation of the XML object?  Then, you could have a factory which would construct a final representation of the XML object using the RequestID.  The code would look similar to:

```
IntermediateObject io = StAX.parse(XML);
FinalObject = Factory.create(io.getRequestID, io);
```

The upside of using this approach is that you're separating responsibilities.  The StAX parser will only parse the XML, while the factory would be responsible for doing further processing with that information.